# Bootstrapping Craft gives fatal error

Tags: bootstrap-craft

I'm using Craft Pro 2.3.2625

I'm trying to write a command-line called script which can call Craft's functions (to create new entries with assets).

Based on Brandon's updated answer here:

[Bootstrap Craft from another app](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/608/bootstrap-craft-from-another-app)

Using:

```
$craft = require 'craft/app/bootstrap.php';
```

in a standalone script should just work after Craft 2.2 - but doing so gives me the following errors (paths tweaked to remove project name):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in craft/app/bootstrap.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in craft/app/bootstrap.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined property: Craft\WebApp::$request in craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php on line 156

Fatal error: Call to a member function isSiteRequest() on a non-object in craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php on line 156
```

Answer (score 3):

That bootstrap file is only meant to be used by web applications. Even if you got past this error, the file is still going to give you a [WebApp](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/WebApp) instance, when what you really want to be working with in that environment is a [ConsoleApp](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/console/ConsoleApp).

If you want to load Craft from the command line, use craft/app/etc/console/yiic instead (make sure it has executable permissions), or if you already have a PHP script running, load yiic.php.

Unfortunately those files don’t work like bootstrap.php though - they will not only instantiate a ConsoleApp instance, they’ll [run it](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#run-detail) as well. So you would need to provide your own functionality through a plugin that adds custom [console commands](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#creating-commands). You would do that by creating a `consolecommands` folder in your plugin folder, with files inside it that end with `Command.php` (e.g. `MyPlugin_UtilsCommand.php`) and a matching class name, which extends [BaseCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/consolecommands/BaseCommand).

More details about how to write the class are available from [BaseCommand’s class reference](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/consolecommands/BaseCommand).